# Why is jupyter-notebook (Anaconda) not running scripts with any of its options?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am trying to run a python script using jupyter notebook but when I hit Shift + Enter on selected cell or click Run from Menu, nothing happens, the control just shifts to next cell downwards.
I closed anaconda and started it again but the issue is not gone.
And then I added Anaconda script folder to my system path but that too did not help.
I was not facing this issue earlier.[image]

Comment: Try restarting the kernel in kernel option. Follow this thread for more : https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11027

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: _And then I added Anaconda script folder to my system path but that too did not help._ What do you mean?

Comment: @AMC I had seen this in some YouTube tutorial, That is why I added Anaconda script folder to my system path but that too did nothing

Comment: The [Anaconda FAQ](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#installing-anaconda) explicitly recommends against that, so just keep that in mind, it could lead to issues down the line.